# How do I install Broadcom's firmware for a PowerPC?

Tags: 12.04, broadcom, powerpc

I'm running 12.04 LTS on a PowerMac G5 and I have one problem. My wireless PCI card has my "Firmware Missing". I already know about Broadcom's poor wireless support with Ubuntu, and it's b43 however whenever I try to install the b43 firmware installer I get this:

```
snackadoodlepop@snackadoodlepop-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer
```

NDIS Wrapper won't work on PowerPC to my knowledge.
I'm stuck without WiFi and I need help!

**SOLVED: Thanks to reddit's /r/linuxquestions, I was able to use the b43 firmware installer correctly.**

Comment: Yo, I got your email. I'll be flying blind, but I'll try and come up with something for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, I got it though I didn't `apt-cache search b43` which fixed it!

Comment: So you installed the `firmware-b43-installer` package, right?

Comment: Yes, and now the wireless card works without a USB for WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search b43
```

To find the firmware package.
Then again:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

You have wireless (but might need to restart first).

Answer (score 4):

spent 2 days and nights trying to set up Ubuntu on my Ibook G4. wireless would not work. I did what said.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search b43
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

you will need to type "y" to confirm disk space is used then it worked